# Load file of content by weight

Tags: database, files

Let's suppose I have a simple content type with `title`, `body` and `file` fields, and `file` field is multi value. I create a piece of content and upload some file in my field. Finally my content is something like

title : my title
body  : somebody text come in body

file  :

1. file1
2. file2
3. file3

**My question**

I can change the order of files in node edit by drag them up or down, I want to know how I can load a file programmatically by its weight. I mean I want to upload a file that is shown first or second in node edit mode. How can I upload file form node programmatically, ordering by weight?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. When you say "load a file programmatically" do you mean UPload a file - ie. changing the node content - or load it in the sense of retrieving it?

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong if we have several field I want load one of them by weight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you change the order, the changes are saved as the delta in the database. For example if your field was called file you would access `$node->field_file[$node->language][delta]`. In your example above, the second file would be `$node->field_file[$node->language][1]` as the first file would be 0

Comment: lastDay I found my solution by looking at database field table. tnx for you attnetion and answer.